# Are *.domain.com wild card SSL certificates expected to or required to only be used by 1 IP?

Tags: ssl, configuration, specifications, ssl-certificate

Are *.domain.com wild card SSL certificates expected to or required to only be used by 1 IP?

Such that

site1.domain.com is on ServerX

and

site2.domain.com is on ServerY

where both servers have unique ip addresses. Is this valid to share the *.domain.com certificate across these servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wildcard certificate with multiple subdomains across multiple IP addresses.  While there is no technical limitation, often Certificate Authorities have licensing restrictions on thier usage.

Comment: I did not realize the single ip facet was a licensing issue, with this information I was able to determine that RapidSSL certificates do not come with this restriction.